# Range value is int

Tags: go

I have a function that needs to cycle over `stopCs` sending a `struct{}{}` message.  Problem is the `stopC` in the range is an `int`. Why, and how do I fix it?

```
func myfunc() {
    var stopCs []chan struct{}

    // Append to stopCs

    return func() {
        for stopC := range stopCs {
            stopC <- struct{}{}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for ... range` statement allows for two types of assignment, the
first is the one you used which iterates over the indices and the second is
the one that iterates over the indices *and the values*. In short, you want

```
for i, stopC := range stopCs {
```

instead of

```
for i := range stopCs {
```

To cite [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause):

> If the last iteration variable is the blank identifier, the range clause is equivalent to the same clause without that identifier.